# call aspx.vb method using ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

my question is the following:

I need to call a paricular method of the code behind file of a particular asp.net webform.

This is my jquery (ajax) function:

```
function LoadPayments(_page) {

    var cliente = 245328;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PayBills.aspx/LoadPayments",
        data: { cod_client: client, page: _page },
        contentType: "application/json: charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false
    })
    .done(function (data) {


    });
}
```

and this is the Function in vb in PayBills.aspx:

```
Protected Sub LoadPayments(cod_client As Integer, page As Integer)
        Dim proxy As proxyWAS = New proxyWAS
        gvDocuments.DataSource = proxy.GetDocumentsList(cod_client, page)
        gvDocuments.DataBind()
End Sub
```

---

Right now I am getting this error: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the **WebMethodAttribute** on the method.

```
Imports System.Web.Services

' Other code ...

<WebMethod()> _
Protected Shared Sub LoadPayments(cod_client As Integer, page As Integer)
    'Dim proxy As proxyWAS = New proxyWAS
    'gvDocuments.DataSource = proxy.GetDocumentsList(cod_client, page)
    'gvDocuments.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Check this [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for information on properties that can be set.

That will call the web method but it will not update the UI.  Doing a databind from an AJAX call is not going to update what is displayed. Either do a postback so the UI can be updated or use the web method call to return HTML that can then be used to update the display.

**Edit** As pointed out by Stryner, the method must be shared on a web method being called from Ajax.  [Here is an explanation on why](http://encosia.com/why-do-aspnet-ajax-page-methods-have-to-be-static/).

The code in your method will not work from an Ajax call.  If you want to use the web form's databinding then use a postback, optionally in an update panel.  If you really want the performance of an Ajax call then you need to create a function that generates the HTML and have JavaScript update the UI.

Comment: A WebMethod in the codebehind of an aspx page also needs the `Shared` modifier.

Comment: Also, keep in mind when trying to refer to a non-shared member of a class from within a **shared** procedure. You will get an error: (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/cannot-refer-to-an-instance-member-of-a-class)